# What subject specific tags could replace the tag 'divisors'?

Tags: discussion, tags

A few names are used in different subjects in mathematics with completely distinct meanings. A couple of common examples are "spectrum" and "regular". Sometimes, this creates problems with tags on MathOverflow, as is explained in some of the answers to the question [Help cleanup tags!](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/862/help-cleanup-tags). Specifically, I want to ask about the tag [divisors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/divisors), which is used for questions concerning:

- divisibility in the integers or in rings, and
- divisors in algebraic geometry.

It may be desirable then to use two more specific tags to replace [divisors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/divisors).

> **Question:** What are your suggestions for the names of those more specific tags which could replace the tag [divisors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/divisors)?
>
> **Generalized question:** Do you suggest any general strategies for naming tags which distinguish the subjects of origin? A hypothetical example is: name tags which distinguish "spectrum" in functional analysis from "spectrum" in algebraic topology.

Comment: The two meanings of "divisors" are closely related, so that a distinction does not seem necessary.

Comment: @FredRohrer abstractly perhaps though even this seems debatable [in view of the fact that AFAIK in the language where 'divisors' in the second meaning originates it is *not* the same word, the first being Teiler in German, and the latter having been introduced by Kronecker (I think)]. But in practice there are really questions that have very little in common all tagged with "divisors".// I do not have a good solution to propse but asked myself the same question at some point.