# Tag warnings on MO

Tags: feature-request, tags, warnings

In the last few months, Stack exchange has introduced tag warnings, that is, a text that is displayed when a user creates a new question that contains a specific warning, such as this example.

[image]

Apparently, the feature has been introduced without a formal announcement by the SE team (or at least I couldn't find any), but word has spread on [several](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21873/do-we-want-tag-warnings-and-for-which-tags) [meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/for-which-tags-if-any-do-we-want-tag-warnings) [sites](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237/tag-warnings-on-ask-ubuntu).

We could use them on MO as well, for instance to disambiguate between words with multiple meanings such as [lattice](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2791/). (This proposal originates from a comment on that thread).

So: **can we have tag warnings too?**

Comment: I am not certain how this works. But I believe we need to come up right away with *specific* proposals that are then implemented. (As opposed to something being "switched on" abstractly first  and us  then turning to details) We could collect the proposals in this thread, as done in the linked to post.

Comment: @quid That makes sense, after seeing the pages on the other metas, but the workflow is not clear at all to me. Do the proposals here get automagically picked up by a Stack Exchange employee? Do they have to get a number of upvotes, or approval from a moderator? Why isn't there a UI to edit tag warnings collectively like there is one for tag excerpts, which would be much simpler? I'd appreciate some clarifications from the SE staff, if someone comes around (and I believe they watch tag:feature-request questions here).

Comment: It is my understanding that this is an experimental feature. It is somewhat invasive too, so I would not make it too simple. But, yes, it could be a per-site moderator thing to manage this (but I don't think it is as of yet). Technically, it seems some SE staff will have to do this "by hand" (like it is for delete or blacklist tags)

Comment: I don't have data on this, but I think tags like "logic" and "proof-theory" are sometimes mistakenly used when the questioner is looking for a proof of some statement. Thus they could deserve a tag warning. (These questions are often at too low a level for MO anyways, but the warning still seems useful...)

Answer (score 8):

There are several tags that [are deprecated](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3261). Adding tag-warnings for them could decrease the probability that they will be added to new questions. (Tag-warnings are more visible than tag-excerpts.)

I would suggest to display simply the information that the tag is deprecated:

- The tag (abstract-algebra) is deprecated, please use other tags instead.
- The tag (discrete-mathematics) is deprecated, please use other tags instead.
- The tag (geometry) is deprecated, please use other tags instead.

Comment: This was also suggested by Federico Poloni in a [comment to another question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2791/what-lattices-do-we-need#comment12655_2791).