# Hadamard product (and other ambiguous tags)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

There is this tag, [hadamard-product](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hadamard-product); as can be seen e. g. on the [Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product), it can have four different meanings. I for one, attracted by it in a [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/269595/41291) (I badly need to simplify Hadamard products of certain series) discovered that it is about the Hadamard product of matrices, which is (an also interesting but) entirely different thing.

I don't know, does it make sense to split such tags? To introduce some disambiguation-like device à la Wikipedia would be sort of overkill I believe...

Previously, there was discussion in [What "lattices" do we need?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2791/what-lattices-do-we-need) that resulted, I believe, in introducing [lattice-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lattice-theory) and leaving [lattices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lattices). I understand this is not ideal but cannot think myself about any better solution. With Hadamard products, it is even worse. [hadamard-product-of-series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hadamard-product-of-series) and [hadamard-product-of-matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hadamard-product-of-matrices) look clumsy, and there still are other two meanings!

Comment: Both (hadamard-product-of-series) and (hadamard-product-of-matrices) are longer that [25 character limit for tag names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain). (But they probably could be shortened in some reasonable way.)

Comment: The current situation is that there are 18 questions tagged ([tag:hadamard-product]). Only 4 of them have [neither linear-algebra nor matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hadamard-product+-linear-algebra+-matrices) tag. Of these four questions, two seem to be related to Riemann function, one is about matrices and one is probably tagged incorrectly. (No mention of Hadamard product, only of Hadamard space.)