# The tags (transcendence) and (transcendental-number-theory)

Tags: discussion, tags

There exist tags [transcendence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/transcendence) and [transcend.-number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/transcend.-number-theory) (probably shortened from [transcendental number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number_theory) to fit 25 characters limit for the tag name). At the moment, the tag-info is empty both for [transcendence](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/transcendence/info) and [transcend.-number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/transcend.-number-theory/info). Looking at the currently tagged questions, the question in both topics are rather similar. The tags currently have 27 and 63 questions, respectively, [overlap](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/transcendence+transcend.-number-theory) is 11 questions.

What exactly are these two tags intended for?

- If they are different, probably the usage of the tags should be clarified in the tag excerpts, so that the users can see there some guidelines to follow.
- If they are the same, then probably one tag would be sufficient.<sup>1</sup>

Here is a [related conversation in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/tags-related-to-transcendental-number-theory).

<sup>1</sup>Perhaps (transcend.-number-theory) is a more descriptive name than simply (transcendence). So if the two tags are supposed to serve the same purpose, perhaps better solution than making a synonym would be removing (transcendence) and replacing it by (transcend.-number-theory). (I vaguely recall that moderators can do this without bumping all questions, probably by merging the tags and then removing the empty one - of course I might remember this incorrectly. But even if the tag can be replaced in most questions without bumping, at least the questions tagged (trancendence) which are not about transcendental number theory would have to be bumped to be retagged correctly.)

P.S. I am aware of the thread [Help improve tagging!](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/194/help-improve-tagging) which serves for suggesting tag synonyms. However, in this case I thought that posting a separate question would be better, since there are several possibilities what - if anything - should be done with these two tags (and the synonym does not seem to be the optimal one).

Comment: A bit off topic: What is the point of "theory" on there?  We have tag (integration), not (integration-theory).  We have (commutative-rings) not (commutative-ring-theory) ... (analytic-number-theory) is OK, it is not about "analytic numbers".

Comment: [transcendental-numbers] has 22 letters.

Comment: In the meantime (transcend.-number-theory) has been renamed to ([tag:transcendental-number-theory]), see also [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/862/help-cleanup-tags/3340#3340).