# Does it make sense to have both "surfaces" and "curves-and-surfaces" tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I have noticed that there currently exist tags [surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/surfaces) (with description *"A surface is a two-dimensional topological manifold. The term can also be used to describe a smooth surface, depending on the context."* and 145 questions tagged) and [curves-and-surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/curves-and-surfaces) (with description *"A surface is a generalization of a plane which needs not be flat, that is, the curvature is not necessarily zero. This is analogous to a curve generalizing a straight line."* and 215 questions tagged).

To me, they seem very similar to each other; wouldn't it be better to melt one of them into the other?

PS: I've just noticed that there also is the [curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/curves) tag, with no description and 53 questions tagged. Maybe remove "curves-and-surfaces" because it mixes two different objects, and manually retag its questions with either "curves" or "surfaces"? (I volunteer to do the retagging.)

Comment: Suggestion to merge these tags [made by quid in 2014](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/194/help-improve-tagging/1459#1459). I suppose this issue might get a bit more attention now that it was posted as a separate question.