# Suggested tag: approximation-property

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm relatively new to MO (but have been on MSE for a longer time), which means that I don't have enough reputation to create new tags. Which is probably a good thing.

Lately I've been puzzling with Banach space tensor products and the approximation property, and on multiple occasions found that my search would have been easier if there had been a tag for questions related to the approximation property. It is my impression that it is a whole field of its own, with a rich body of theory and (especially) counterexamples, so to me a tag `approximation-property` would make sense.

Since I understand that we don't want to go haphazardly creating new tags for every specialization (or niche) within mathematics, I thought I'd ask what you think. Has this been considered before? Do we like the idea? Do we hate it? Should we consider variations on the proposal (e.g. a tag `metric-theory-of-tensor-products`)?

---

Added later: as per François' suggestion, here is my suggested tag info.

> For questions relating to various approximation properties in functional analysis and (abstract) harmonic analysis, including approximation properties of Banach spaces, locally convex spaces, operator algebras, and locally compact groups.

Furthermore, I tried to compile a list of questions to which the new tag would apply. Note that this list might be incomplete, again because I found it difficult to find all relevant questions on this topic. (Some would only mention the term "AP", so those would be hard to track down. This applies to one of the questions below – I only found it because it happened to be linked to another question on my list.)

*Questions directly related to the approximation property (sorted by publication date).*

- [Approximation Property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17801/approximation-property)
- [Banach lattice with AP but without BAP?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31537/banach-lattice-with-ap-but-without-bap)
- [Examples of groups without the n-positive approximation property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32147/examples-of-groups-without-the-n-positive-approximation-property)
- [Are the compact and Haagerup approximation properties equivalent?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39808/are-the-compact-and-haagerup-approximation-properties-equivalent)
- [What Approximation Property does the space of Schatten-p class operators have?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136350/what-approximation-property-does-the-space-of-schatten-p-class-operators-have)
- [The approximation property of group C*-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139545/the-approximation-property-of-group-c-algebras)
- [A question on $p$-approximation property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179493/a-question-on-p-approximation-property)
- [$C^*$-algebra generated by those operators that are bounded on every $\ell_p$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191919/c-algebra-generated-by-those-operators-that-are-bounded-on-every-ell-p)
- [Compact Approximation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196097/compact-approximation)
- [Approximation Property: Characterization](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196100/approximation-property-characterization)
- [Approximation Property: Decomposition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196110/approximation-property-decomposition)
- [A question on metric characterization of approximation property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196155/a-question-on-metric-characterization-of-approximation-property)
- [Ultraweak topology on B(X): Is the map X\otimes X* -> B(X)* isometric?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198466/ultraweak-topology-on-bx-is-the-map-x-otimes-x-bx-isometric)
- [Does the Approximation Property (AP) pass to quotients by amenable subgroups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199122/does-the-approximation-property-ap-pass-to-quotients-by-amenable-subgroups)
- [For discrete groups, does the Haagerup property imply the AP of Haagerup-Kraus?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202835/for-discrete-groups-does-the-haagerup-property-imply-the-ap-of-haagerup-kraus)
- [Is there a quotient of $c_0$ without the approximation property?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212566/is-there-a-quotient-of-c-0-without-the-approximation-property)
- [Weakenings of the Bounded Approximation Property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230707/weakenings-of-the-bounded-approximation-property)
- [Compact non-nuclear operators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237804/compact-non-nuclear-operators)
- [A variant of the approximation property?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254473/a-variant-of-the-approximation-property)
- [Does the Banach algebra of jets have the approximation property?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254496/does-the-banach-algebra-of-jets-have-the-approximation-property)
- [CBAP for the full group $C^*$-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263904/cbap-for-the-full-group-c-algebra)
- [Tensors and Nuclear/Fredholm Operators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265130/tensors-and-nuclear-fredholm-operators)
- [The approximation property for some spaces of holomorphic functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278184/the-approximation-property-for-some-spaces-of-holomorphic-functions)
- [Completely bounded maps approximately factoring through finite matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291015/completely-bounded-maps-approximately-factoring-through-finite-matrices)
- [Does Thompson's group $V$ have property AP?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296246/does-thompsons-group-v-have-property-ap)
- [Approximation property counterexamples? (Also: relation to tensor products)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304198/approximation-property-counterexamples-also-relation-to-tensor-products)
- [A characterization of nuclear functionals in terms of continuity with respect to some special topologies on $B(X)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327888/a-characterization-of-nuclear-functionals-in-terms-of-continuity-with-respect-to)
- [A question on the metric approximation property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337889/a-question-on-the-metric-approximation-property)
- [Do the operators in $B(E,F)$ separate points on the projective tensor product $F' \mathop{\tilde\otimes_\pi} E$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339378/do-the-operators-in-be-f-separate-points-on-the-projective-tensor-product-f)

*Questions tangentially related to the approximation property (sorted by publication date).*

- [Projective and injective tensor product](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74007/projective-and-injective-tensor-product)
- [tr(ab)=tr(ba), part 2.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76604/trab-trba-part-2)
- [Denseness of finite rank operators in $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171802/denseness-of-finite-rank-operators-in-mathcalbx-y)
- [Approximation property of Fréchet if range is restricted to an embedded Hilbert space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201448/approximation-property-of-fr%C3%A9chet-if-range-is-restricted-to-an-embedded-hilbert)
- [A "slice-map" type problem for symmetric tensors in the square of a nuclear C*-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206181/a-slice-map-type-problem-for-symmetric-tensors-in-the-square-of-a-nuclear-c-a)
- [Noncommutative analogs of classical Banach geometric properties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211845/noncommutative-analogs-of-classical-banach-geometric-properties)
- [Outline of Generic Separable Banach Spaces don't have a Schauder Basis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220752/outline-of-generic-separable-banach-spaces-dont-have-a-schauder-basis)
- [Do there exist infinite-dimensional Banach spaces in which every bounded linear operator attains its norm?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232291/do-there-exist-infinite-dimensional-banach-spaces-in-which-every-bounded-linear)
- [Characterization of exact groups via the existence of amenable actions on unital C*-algebras, part 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255246/characterization-of-exact-groups-via-the-existence-of-amenable-actions-on-unital)
- [On the relation between Lipschitz free-spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270151/on-the-relation-between-lipschitz-free-spaces)
- [Are ideals in separable C*-algebras complemented subspaces?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271293/are-ideals-in-separable-c-algebras-complemented-subspaces)
- [Nuclear operators and their eigenvalues](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304426/nuclear-operators-and-their-eigenvalues)
- [When does the dual to the space $K(X)$ of compact operators consist of nuclear functionals?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327418/when-does-the-dual-to-the-space-kx-of-compact-operators-consist-of-nuclear-f)

*Questions containing the term "approximation property" which nevertheless fall outside the scope of the proposed tag (mostly regarding different approximation properties, e.g. in algebra or logic).*

- [Real approximation for homogeneous spaces of linear algebraic groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50570/real-approximation-for-homogeneous-spaces-of-linear-algebraic-groups)
- [Infinitely many solutions of a diophantine equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51263/infinitely-many-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation)
- [What could be some potentially useful mathematical databases?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68442/what-could-be-some-potentially-useful-mathematical-databases)
- [Class number of PGL_2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80904/class-number-of-pgl-2)
- [Are there lightweight foundations for arbitrarily extendable objects?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93303/are-there-lightweight-foundations-for-arbitrarily-extendable-objects)
- [Analytic elements in non-archimedean geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105080/analytic-elements-in-non-archimedean-geometry)
- [Is there a truth approximation on a‎ cumulative hierarchy‎‎‎‎?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141857/is-there-a-truth-approximation-on-a-cumulative-hierarchy)
- [A cohomology group which depends on the connection](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172081/a-cohomology-group-which-depends-on-the-connection)
- [Preserving Jonsson cardinals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191071/preserving-jonsson-cardinals)
- [The $\delta$-approximation property for ground models](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286055/the-delta-approximation-property-for-ground-models)
- [If the finitely additive measure of an open set is approximable by clopen sets, is it approximable from within?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325806/if-the-finitely-additive-measure-of-an-open-set-is-approximable-by-clopen-sets)

Comment: My two cents: at the very least a tag `metric-theory-of-tensor-products` seems superfluous. Questions regarding e.g. tensor products of Banach spaces can easily be found by combining the tags `banach-spaces` and `tensor-products`.

Comment: Are there existing questions where the tag would apply? (Tags can't be created for their own sake, they need to be applied to a question.)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais by my count, at least somewhere between 30 and 50 existing questions would fall under this tag.

Comment: Allright, help people out and create a list of questions that would benefit from this tag! For additional traction, you could also propose a tag info blurb.

Comment: Done! I think my proposed tag info should be checked by an expert. For instance, I don't know too much about the (Haagerup) approximation property for locally compact groups, but I get the feeling that it is related to other approximation properties in functional analysis (maybe via the group algebra?), and therefore should be included in this tag (which is what I've done now). But I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: This is wonderful! I think this is now a model tag request. (Which we needed.) I am not at all an expert in this area but I hope experts will chime in sooner than later.

Comment: I read [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property) that the term *approximation property* is also [used in ring theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property_(ring_theory)). Should it be explicitly mentioned in tag-info (perhaps tag-wiki if not tag-excerpt) that this is not meant for ring theory? Would it perhaps be better to choose the tagname which would distinguish this from algebra, for example, (approximation-property-analysis)?

Comment: I confirm that the various approximation properties for locally compact groups (mainly the AP of Haagerup and Kraus and weak amenability, but also the Haagerup property) fit perfectly well in the description of the tag. The reason for their introduction by Haagerup and coauthors is that for discrete groups, they characterize corresponding approximations properties (à la Grothendieck) of the operators algebras of the group.

Comment: I think that all this is excellent, but unfortunately this tag will attract a large number of off-tag questions (typing "approximation" will propose this tag, and whatever good the tag info is, many users, especially new ones, do not read it or ignore it).

Comment: @YCor That is somewhat similar situation to the (divisors) tag, in this case, there is a [suggestion to change the name of the tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/194/help-improve-tagging/3596#3596). Do you have some name that would fit 35 characters and be distinctive enough to prevent the incorrect usage? The name (approximation-theory-analysis) suggested in a previous comment could probably still be misused. And alternative would be (approximation-property-funct-an) - or something similar within the character limit - however I don't really like such shortening.

Comment: That's a fair point, but bear in mind that typing "approximation" first shows [tag:approximation-theory], [tag:diophantine-approximation], and [tag:approximation-algorithms]. Wouldn't they go with approximation theory instead?

Comment: Otherwise, perhaps `operator-approximation-property`?

Comment: It has come to my attention that one particular version of the approximation property is called "operator approximation property" (OAP). (This is not the classical approximation property.) So I guess the suggestion from the preceding comment might falsely suggest that the tag focuses exclusively on this OAP, as opposed to any kind of AP. Therefore I change my previous suggestion to `operator-approximation-properties`.

Comment: (By the way, I'm still in favour of calling it simply `approximation-property`. I don't think it'll be so bad. But then, what do I know?)

Comment: @J.vanDobbendeBruyn I will just point out that mods can rename a tag - so it's possible to rename it later if the tag becomes problematic. (Technically, it is merging into another tag rather than renaming. But the end result is a tag containing the same question with a new name. See also:[How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87437#197731) and [Can you change the name of a tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25699#25701))